# Data type "NULL" values

Tags: sql

How do I know  which datatype will accept `Null` value and which datatype will not accept null value in SQL.

Comment: Data types don't "accept" NULL values. Columns do. And every column that is not defined as `NOT NULL`  can contain a `NULL` value regardless of the data type.

Comment: null values are not datatype specific they are column specific. as when you give which column should accept null.

Comment: NULL isn't really a value, it's rather a "non existing value".

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> which datatype will accept null value??

**NULL** means **ABSENCE** of data. Means any datatype without value can have `NULL` value.